# Mock Methods that are not virtual

Tags: c++, c++11, googlemock

I have a class say A like mentioned below :

```
class A
{
void show()
{}
int data(int x)
{}
.....
};
```

I need to mock the class - since the member functions are not virtual - can I design my mock class like mentioned below:

```
class MockA : public A
{
MOCK_METHIOD0(show, void ());
MOCK_METHIOD1(data, int (int));
}
```

Can I implement this way and is there a chance from MockA to miss out mocking of 
any function of class A?
Objects created using MockA will ever anyway land up calling class A actual method implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally for this case you do not have the mock inherit from `A` and instead use a compile time mechanism to select whether to use an implementation class or a mock class. E.g. templating everything that uses `A` and then instantiating the templates with either `A` or `MockA`, to replace the production class with the mock one in the testing setup. Any methods that are not implemented in the mock, but which are called, result in a compile time error. The use of the macros in the mock definition are pretty much the same even though the methods are non-virtual.

The hard part is replacing the class everywhere. Templates, referencing the class name via a macro, or using the same class name and making sure only one is linked are all possibilities.

Comment: But will above method not override the actual implementation if objects are created with MockA?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "override the actual implementation." Non-virtual methods are linked by name, thus the compiler is either generating a direct call to e.g. either `A::show` or `MockA::show`. Note that even in the virtual method case one doesn't generally have the mock inherit from an implementation, but from an interface that the implementation also inherits from.